# Reflexive sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I was looking for properties of reflexive sheaves on a variety.
Suppose $X\rightarrow Y$ is etale outside codimension two subset. Say $X$ is smooth.
Is the pullback of a reflexive sheaf on $Y$,  reflexive on $X$.

Comment: Dear John, Outside of codim'n two on $X$ or on $Y$?  Regards,

Comment: Karl's answer modifies to an counterexample even if $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic in codim $2$, for example, consider the blowup $k[x,y,z,w]/(xy-zw)$ along the plane $x=z=0$, then locally the map reads $k[x,y,z,w]/(xy-zw)\to k[x,z,w], x\mapsto x, y\mapsto zw, z\mapsto zx, w\mapsto w$, the pullback of the ideal $(y,z)$ has an nontrivial element $y\otimes x-z\otimes w$ annihilated by $yz$.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is not true.  For example, what if $X \to Y$ is a resolution of singularities, that's even an isomorphism outside a set of codimension 2.  The pullback of reflexive sheaves is definitely not reflexive.

For example, consider the blowup of the origin in $R = k[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2) = k[a^2, b^2, ab]$.  One of the charts in that blowup is $k[a^2, b/a]$.  The pullback of the reflexive sheaf $(a^2, ab)$ in that chart is the tensor product $(a^2, ab) \otimes_R k[a^2, b/a]$.  Then the element
$$a^2 \otimes (b/a) - ab \otimes 1$$
is clearly torsion and non-zero.

What people do frequently do is the reflexive pullback.  In other words, pullback and then reflexify.

From the point of view of singularities, you might look at a paper of de Fernex and Hacon on singularities in non-Q-Gorenstein rings.  There are other sources I can point you towards (say Hassett and Kov\'acs) if you are more interested in moduli types of applications.